# Are remnants of the Husnock civilization ever found?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-eu

Kevin Uxbridge admitted to killing all the Husnock in the third season TNG episode "The Survivors."  The Husnock were never seen or heard of again in the TV series.  However, there are many Star Trek novels offering further adventures of the Enterprise crew and other Star Trek characters.  Assuming Uxbridge only wiped out the Husnock people, their artifacts should still be around to be found eventually.  Are remnants of the Husnock civilization ever found in any of the Star Trek novels?

Comment: The Douwd claimed to destroy "all Husnock...everywhere." No mention of the Douwd eliminating Husnock from the past, though, or in alternate universes or dimensions, etc. Time travel in Star Trek is as common as holodeck problems, so unless the Douwd's "power" is able to continuously "watch over" the cosmos and prevent any external Husnock from entering, I don't see why the universe could not some day be repopulated by the Husnock.

Comment: Good point about the parallel universes as well as time travel.  But it would be kinda like bringing back the dinosaurs.  Other than in some crazy theme park, who'd want to bring back the Husnock?  The galaxy has enough bloody-handed conquerors already.  And bringing them back might really piss Uxbridge off, too.

Comment: I could see Q bringing back the Husnock, just to annoy the Douwd. But seriously, it wouldn't require someone actively doing this. The Husnock in question may be involved in a bizzare shuttlecraft accident that propels them 200 years into the future---the Douwd's time. Or whatever. So, unless the Douwd literally eliminated ALL Husnock (surely not possible even for him), then a comeback could be acheived at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The legacy of the Husnok is explored in the upcoming Star Trek Titan novel [Fortune of War](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06ZZ1YDYY) by David Mack.  From Amazon.com:

> Twenty years have passed since the interstellar scourge known as the Husnock were exterminated without warning by a being with godlike abilities. Left behind, intact but abandoned, their desolate worlds and derelict ships brim with destructive potential.

Comment: Can you provide a link to somewhere to support this? An announcement, maybe?

Comment: @Gallifreyan I found it on Amazon and added some information.

Comment: Excellent.  This is exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 6):

No mentions of real Husnock are in [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/index.php?search=Husnock&fulltext=Search) (which covers books etc... in Star Trek franchise). Not an conclusive proof, but Memory Beta is usually pretty thorough.

However, RPG sourcebook "[Through a Glass, Darkly](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Through_a_Glass,_Darkly)" covered [Husnock](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Husnock_%28planet%29_%28mirror%29) in the [mirror universe](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Mirror_universe).

> Husnock was a planet which came under the control of the Terran Empire some time during the mid to late 23rd century.
>   Under imperial control, the entire planet served as a containment camp for the native and psychotically violent species of the planet who were also known as the Husnock.

Comment: Memory Alpha also says ' "The Survivors" remains the Husnock's sole "appearance" in Star Trek.' but it's not clear if that statement includes the Beta (non-canon) appearances.

Comment: It's a pretty safe bet that Memory Alpha's note excludes non-canon things - there's an "Apocrypha" section that they use when they want to include stuff from the novels/etc

Comment: @Izkata - that seems to be the pattern from limited pages on MA I perused, but I didn't feel confortable relying on it as I'm not sure if it's a rule.